# Is there a way to tell Visual Studio to treat a warning as a warning, not an error?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, compiler-warnings

In Visual Studio, [warning C4996](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-3-c4996?view=msvc-160) (using a deprecated function) is treated as an error, and code that uses deprecated functions doesn't compile at all.

There are various ways to disable C4996 entirely, either suppressing it for a single line, for a translation unit, or for an entire project. But what if I want it to still raise a warning, but allow compilation while not treating it as an error?

```
#include <iostream>

[[deprecated]]
void deprecated_function()
{
    std::cout << "I function, but have been deprecated.\n";
}

int main() {
    deprecated_function();
}
```

This doesn't compile at all.

```
#include <iostream>

[[deprecated]]
void deprecated_function()
{
    std::cout << "I function, but have been deprecated.\n";
}

int main() {
#pragma warning(suppress: 4996)
    deprecated_function();
}
```

This compiles, but doesn't issue a warning at all.

Is it possible to tell Visual Studio to emit a warning, but still allow compilation, for a deprecated function? I'm thinking of refactoring purposes, where I'd like to mark a function as deprecated, identify all the places it's used, but the code still compiles at each intermediate stage where some but not all uses of the deprecated function have been replaced.

I'm compiling using Visual Studio 2019 Community 16.8.4, warning level set to /W3, "Treat Warnings as Errors" set to "No". This particular warning seems to be treated as an error if it gets emitted at all.

Comment: Are you compiling with warnings as errors?

Comment: No, it treats this warning as an error even if I have "Treat Warnings as Errors" set to "No (/Wx-)"

Comment: I don't see that happening [here on Godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/h4x133).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found a working solution. It turns out the relevant flag is actually "[SDL checks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/sdl-enable-additional-security-checks)", not "Treat Warnings as Errors". Flipping it from `/sdl` to `/sdl-` causes compilation to emit a warning while still compiling.

EDIT: If I want to keep all the SDL checks on *except* treating Warning C4996 as an error, I can use the flag `/sdl` in combination with the flag `/w34996`, which specifies that `4996` is treated as a level 3 warning instead of an error.

Comment: Indeed, `C4996` is one of the warnings that [`/sdl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/sdl-enable-additional-security-checks?view=msvc-160) turns into errors.

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.